# Yii2 ajax update

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Есть метод для обновления страницы посредством ajax

```
public function actionUpdate( $id )
{
    $page = Page::find( $id )->one();

    if ( Yii::$app->request->post() )
    {
        $page->attributes = \Yii::$app->request->post('Page');

        if ( $page->validate() && $page->save() )
        {
            return $this->actionUpdate( $page->id );
        }
    }

    if( $page !== null )
    {
        if ( Yii::$app->request->isAjax )
        {
            return $this->renderAjax( '_form', [ 'model' => $page ] );
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render( 'update', [ 'model' => $page ] );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('Page not found');
    }
}
```

После обновления нужно остаться на редактируемой странице, обновив инфу. Но проблема в том, что оно уходит в цикл, т.е. получаю что-то вроде рекурсии :(

Comment: не пробовали pjax? и чем не подошло если пробовали?

Comment: Про pjax в курсе, но не вижу в нем особого смысла. Как сказано здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612462/how-is-pjax-working

 _It's just a wrapper around "$.ajax()"_

Comment: Возможно вам надо сделать `return $this->renderAjax('_form')` или `return ['success' => $page->save()];`

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал

`return $this->renderAjax('_form')`

Хотя странно, return вроде как должен останавливать дальнейшее выполнение скрипта 

`return $this->actionUpdate( $page->id );`

А он его по кругу гоняет :(

Comment: ну тут как.. в начале выполняется правая часть, а затем делается `return`, например `return 2+3;` выполнится в начале сложение..... соответственно, у вас постоянно в начале он хочет выполнить экшн апдейт, а до `return` соответственно и не доходит

Comment: а вообще, наверное `return $this->renderAjax('_form')` не правильно, правильно будет `return ['success' => $page->save()]` или любой другой `return`. Т.к. по факту аяксом делают как правило для того, чтоб обработать что-то без перезагрузки страницы и обработать ответ, вернувшийся с контроллера....а `renderAjax('_form')` как-то глупо в этой ситуации.... особенно если вы никак ответ потом не обрабатываете..... обычно на клиенте пишут что-то типа `.success: function(response) { if (response.success) { // do smth.} }`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, пойду дальше копать эту тему. Спорных моментов очень много.